# Internal standard with low T1 for NMR quantification of ammonia

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I am trying to quantify low levels of ammonia with NMR. The good news is that ammonia has a very low T1 (<0.5) which shortens d1 a lot. However, I cannot find any internal standard with a T1 that is as low as ammonia so that I can use absolute qNMR for quantification. For example maleic acid would require around 10 times longer relaxation, because the T1 is around 3-5s which reduces the LOD of cause.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Can you say more about your sample? You are willing to add an internal qNMR standard, what about a relaxation agent ?

Comment: Basically it's just ammonia in water. We tried iron as relaxation agent with maleic acid as internal standard. It decreases the T1 but also the sensitivity for ammonia due to line broadening.

Comment: You might want to try other relaxation agents and pick your concentration carefully. The combination maleic acid + iron sounds bad because they may form a complex (for quantitation that may not matter depending how the sample is prepared).

Comment: I take that back: the formation of a complex may be *very bad* for quantitation if it is a tight complex, resulting in very rapid relaxation of the complexed maleate. There are other choices, however N-14 relaxation will be a problem with ammonia.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense that maleic acid and iron from a complex, because our data was not quantitative (no linearity). However, we found that the LOD for ammonia becomes much worse due to line broadening which is a problem, because we need high sensitivity. Do you know any relaxation agents that don't cause line broadening for ammonia? I must admit I don't understand the theory behind relaxation agents so this might be a stupid question, haha

Comment: There is a vast literature on the subject of relaxation agents. Among the common ones in nmr are GdCl3 and Cr(acac)3 and some nickel salts. Their effect may vary but typically insofar relaxation is concerned they shorten T1/2 for small molecules to the same degree (for small molecules T1~=T2).

Comment: It is difficult to give further opinion for your particular case. The chemistry of combining all of the ingredients you mention may be complex. I am not sure changing relaxation agent would make much of a difference insofar as ammonia versus maleic acid is concerned. Feel free to post a more specific question or even data if you need an opinion.

Comment: Do you know if there are any relaxation agents that don't cause line broadening? I don't feel competent enough to discuss this subject. Can you recommend a nice review paper?

Comment: You may want to read eg     P. Caravan
    Strategies for increasing the sensitivity of gadolinium based MRI contrast agents,    Chem. Soc. Rev., 35 (2006), pp. 512-523. This article may give you pointers on what you *don't want*, ironically. You want something that *doesnt* relax water quickly. The opposite of the usual goal.